# Should I be using REST or SOAP UI for testing?

Tags: rest, soap, soapui

I am testing a new webservice that is receiving messages from an application and responding with messages with specific information. The webservice then uses this information to create new messages for downstream systems. I need to know the best way I can test this using the Ready API tool, we just got a pro license. Is it SOAP or REST I need to use. Ideally I want to simply copy my application messages in to the tool, call the webservice and get the response, which I can then check is the correct response for the test

Answer (score 1):

To find your web-service is SOAP or REST.

Please check whether your web service has WSDL to verify it has SOAP web-service, you can get your web-service's WSDL by post-fixing WSDL with your web service url.

Eg: `http://{yourservice-url/path1}?WSDL`

If your service don't provide WSDL from the above URL, then your web-service is REST.

Comment: Not every SOAP service automatically exposes its service contract via the `?WSDL` parameter. I know some proprietary frameworks that use SOAP that don't expose a WSDL directly. Some ship it with their product documentation only and some offer an own DNS-like service, such as in the case of Peppol AS4, that is build on top of SOAP.

Comment: I have found out it is a REST webservice. Will this make it more difficult to test without a WSDL ?

Comment: REST web-service doesn't have WSDL. REST may have WADL, it can be imported for testing. If WADL is not available create request as per spec/swagger provided .